# Python numerical calculation concerns

Tags: python, python-2.x

I computed the following 2 values in python and got different results! It would be great if someone could reason it why it is happening like this.

`(111 - (111 + 2*17)*3375)/(-14)` gives 34947 as output.

`(111 - (111 + 2*17)*3375)/(14)*-1` gives 34948 as output.

Both terms are mathematically equivalent.

Comment: please post what you actually entered....`(14)-1` is 13 ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with the rounding rules. Consider a simpler example:

```
>>> -3/(-2)
1

>>> -3/2*-1
2
```

`1.5` is rounded **down** to `1`, and `-1.5` is rounded **down** to `-2`. Consistent, in a way.

[Doc reference:](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)

> Plain or long integer division yields an integer of the same type; the
>   result is that of mathematical division with the ‘floor’ function
>   applied to the result.

If you want a floating point result in Python 2.x, you need either an explicit conversion (or just use float literals), or do `from __future__ import division`. In Python 3.x, division always produces a float ([ref](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)).

Comment: It is worth noting that in Python 3 `//` means "integer division" and `/` means "floating point division."

Comment: @maxywb Yes, I'd say "floor division" and just "division" (they are called so in the documentation I link to, FWIW). Both exist in Python 2. But the division behaves differently on integers in 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing integer math, which rounds the fractional result differently depending on whether it's negative or positive. Using floating point division:

```
>>> (111 - (111 + 2*17)*3375)/(14.)*(-1)
34947.42857142857
>>> (111 - (111 + 2*17)*3375)/(-14.)
34947.42857142857
```

Comment: Well, it's more accurate to say that the result is always rounded toward negative infinity (not that it's "different" for negative or positive results).

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to the way that python handles integer division.

If iether the numerator(top) or divisor(bottom) of your division is negative then python will round away from zero. A simple way to convince yourself of this is to compare two simpler fractions: `25/6` and `25/(-6)`.  These will yield 4 and -5 respectively.

In order to get the same results you could us a float ie 14.0 to shift to floating point arithmatic.

If you are interested in more of the mathematics this seemed to be a pretty good article:
http://python-history.blogspot.co.nz/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier python division and rounding seems issue
Here is how to fix it

```
In [10]: int((111 - (111 + 2*17)*3375)/(-14.0))
Out[10]: 34947

In [11]: int((111 - (111 + 2*17)*3375)/(14.0)*-1 )
Out[11]: 34947
```